# Video with corrupted duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to know how I can do this video :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/546763235051700314/709949399551180910/C.webm
(The corrupted duration https://prnt.sc/sm5188 )
"Duration: 154855045:51:26.21, start: -0.002000, bitrate: N/A"
Do anyone have a command for do that, and with what (ffmpeg, [...])
Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remux it.

```
ffmpeg -i current.webm -c copy new.webm
```

Comment: Works here. Upgrade ffmpeg.

Comment: Oh and it's work but the duration is correct and I want it to be "corrupted" but playable,
Sorry for my english, I'm French

Comment: C.webm = https://prnt.sc/sm9fj3
new.webm = https://prnt.sc/sm9gcg

Comment: Can I just copy the settings and paste it to a another video ?

Comment: ffmpeg will not purposely generate a video with invalid duration.

Comment: Yup, I found out that it's a file modification : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHQ7dW6M2s